# Flipping texture after its model matrix transposition in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix, transpose

In OpenGL we have z direction forward (into the screen ) as negative value.I transpose the model matrix (plane primitive) to make it positive.But there is a problem -The texture becomes flipped in local X axis.I can flip it doing negative scaling of X axis of the matrix.Is there a more elegant ways to achieve this?

Comment: It is typical 4x4 transformation matrix. See C++ glm  library .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I transpose the model matrix (plane primitive) to make it positive.

Don't do that. If you want to make +Z forward, you want to *negate* the Z. That means creating a scale matrix with a -1 in the Z.

Comment: @MichaelIV: You wanted to negate the meaning of Z, so that's how you do it. It has nothing to do with performance. Transposing the matrix is the wrong way to solve the problem. Just as multiplying two numbers is the wrong operation if you want to find the sum of those numbers.